# WebAPI - return file and additional data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I need WebAPI method, which returns file and some additional data. I try to do it:

```
        HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse<OCRResult>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ocrResult);
        var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\\_forTest.jpg", FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName("_forTest.jpg");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        return result;
```

but I see only file in returned result, not additional json data (of course, content type is not json). How to "combine" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of the `Request.CreateResponse<T>` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969056(v=vs.118).aspx

> value: The *content* of the HTTP response message.

So basically, you put `ocrResult` as the content of your message, then overwrite it right after:

```
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
```

In any case, you can't send a file **and** display content at the same time in an HTTP response. This is because both are actually sent the same way (and the content-type tells the browser whether it is displayable content or a file). That's why most websites display a content page with an automatic redirection, and the message "your download will start in a few seconds".